# Bash string manipulation with/without whitespaces

Tags: string, bash, list, syntax

Consider having a String in bash holding a list of items:

```
# BLUBB="item foobar blubb bar"
```

Further consider having an exclude list of items:

```
# EXCLUDE="item bar blubb"
```

What would be the easiest way to resolve this to a list holding BLUBB w/o EXCLUDE. My first approach was:

```
# for i in $EXCLUDE; do BLUBB=${BLUBB//$i/}; done
```

But this additionally removes the `bar` from `foobar`. So it seems, one has to look for whitespace or nothing before and after the `$i`. How is the syntax for this?

Comment: Are you set on doing this using pure bash? Are you using a version that supports arrays?

Comment: At least I want to. The version is `# bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`.

Comment: You can do this: `for i in $EXCLUDE; do BLUBB=${BLUBB//#$i/}; done` This would remove the `bar` if it's at the beginning of the word. But it would also remove `barfoo` if there's one.

Comment: Doing this with strings means your "words" can never contain spaces or shell glob characters because otherwise the expansion will word-split and glob them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this can be done:

```
#/bin/bash
BLUBB="item foobar blubb bar"
EXCLUDE="item bar blubb"
for word in ${BLUBB} ${EXCLUDE} ${EXCLUDE}; do
    echo ${word}
done | sort | uniq -u
```

Comment: Good enough for me. The second `${EXCLUDE}` can be omitted, I guess... ;) Thanks!

Comment: I think you need the second exclude to exclude any words in `${EXCLUDE}` that don't appear in `${BLUBB}`.

Comment: @ferdy, as Etan says, the 2nd EXCLUDE is needed, because if you have a word in it, which is not in BLUBB, it will also be printed

Comment: Thanks to both of you. To finalize, what I wanted, the complete solution to this would look like this: 

    `BLUBB="$(for i in ${BLUBB} ${EXCLUDE} ${EXCLUDE}; do echo "$i" ; done | sort | uniq -z | tr '\n' ' ')"`

and then to eliminate the trailing space: 

   `BLUBB=${BLUBB% *}`

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this in bash with an associative array:

```
$ BLUBB="item foobar blubb bar"
$ EXCLUDE="item bar blubb"
$ declare -A h
$ for word in $BLUBB; do h[$word]=1; done
$ declare -p h
declare -A h='([blubb]="1" [bar]="1" [foobar]="1" [item]="1" )'
$ for word in $EXCLUDE; do unset "h[$word]"; done
$ declare -p h
declare -A h='([foobar]="1" )'
$ words="${!h[*]}"
$ echo "$words"
foobar
```

If any of the "words" in BLUBB or EXCLUDE contain whitespace, you have to use indexed arrays to hold them:

```
$ BLUBB=(item foobar blubb bar "word with spaces")
$ EXCLUDE=(item bar blubb with)
$ declare -A h
$ for elem in "${BLUBB[@]}"; do h["$elem"]=1; done
$ for elem in "${EXCLUDE[@]}"; do unset "h[$elem]"; done
$ declare -p h
declare -A h='(["word with spaces"]="1" [foobar]="1" )'
```